# How to change the format of training data for custom NER model retraining using SpaCy?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, spacy

I am working on this problem where the text data is in the a document file and the resulting 5 tags are in a csv file. So to train `spaCy NER` model, we have to tag dtaa something like :

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("Who is Shaka Khan?", {"entities": [(7, 17, "PERSON")]}),
    ("I like London and Berlin.", {"entities": [(7, 13, "LOC"), (18, 24, "LOC")]}),
]
```

But my data is in csv file like:

[image]

I wrote a function which will search the first occurrences of `col query` in the text and add the length. Something like:

```
train_data = []
for i,index in enumerate(df.index.tolist()):
    row_data = df.iloc[i,:].values.tolist()
    entities = {"entities":[]}
    for file in dir_files:
        if file.split('.')[0] == row_data[0]:
            text = preprocess(textract.process("./Training_data/"+file))
            
            for j,entry in enumerate(row_data[1:]):
                
                if not pd.isna(entry):
                    if isinstance(entry,str): # takes care of null values
                        entities['entities'].append((text.find(str(entry).strip()),len(str(entry)),ent_names[j]))
```

and the result is

```
{'entities': [(-1, 7, 'Aggrement Value'),
  (-1, 10, 'Aggrement Start Date'),
  (-1, 10, 'Aggrement End Date'),
  (-1, 4, 'Renewal Notice (Days)'),
  (124, 22, 'Party One'),
  (540, 45, 'Party Two')]}
```

It is giving me decent results for the `STRING` but I have a huge problem for date as the are in format `12.08.2018` and price which is format `6000.00`. I can't compare directly so I have to change the price `str(int(price))` and then match. It'll work BUT the date is never in the format given in CSV. It's spmething like `1stDAY OF SEPTEMBER 2018 TWO THOUSAND EIGHTEEN`. How am I supposed to tag that one in format?

I tried using `Spacy's` inbuilt NER so that I could figure out but it is not giving me good results.

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(preprocess(text))
displacy.render(nlp(doc.text),style='ent',jupyter=True)
```

It gives me something like:

[image]

How can I tag my data because without proper tagging of dates, it's all futile as it'll never learn to get the dates no matter what.
Is there any `Regular expression RE` or I saw that [NLTK POS based Queries to extract NER](https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-with-nltk-and-spacy-8c4a7d88e7da)  gives us something like:

[image]

Comment: Show your input text, describe your problem in the current approach, and show the desired output.

Comment: @Deshwal: if you find my answer useful, could you please mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to robustly parse dates which are given mostly in a fully textual form.

To normalize such dates you can attempt to use one of [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [`maya`](https://pypi.org/project/maya/), [`pendulum`](https://pendulum.eustace.io/) or [`arrow`](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) libraries. Good demonstration of possibilities of these libraries you can find [here](https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/).

In case your problem is also to tag the dates in text, it is a bit more nuanced and you would have to train such a model if SpaCy / NLTK is not suitable for your purpose. You can theoretically also implement a number of regular expressions but this is error prone and would take months to complete. AFAIK, there is no robust implementation available.